# Using subscripts and variables for multiple legends for R plots

Tags: r, plot, environment-variables, legend, subscript

My goal is to have multiple lines in my legend that would look like this format, Nsubscript(M), Nsubscript(F). The subscripts will be used to make my legend shorthand. There will be variables that will need to be evaluated to get the numeric values. How do I  make multiple lines of legends with subscripts and variables?

I  need to be get multiple bquotes to work. The format below is what I want for the legend part.

```
#this works 
N_male<-4#random variable
N_female<-6#random variable 
plot(x=2,y=3)#random plot
legend("topright",legend=bquote('N'['F']*' = '*.( N_female)),
text.col="black",box.col=0, bty="n", cex = .75, lty= c(2)) #this legend has 
#correct syntax
```

However I need to get multiple bquotes to work in the same legend. How do I do that?

```
#this does not work
N_male<-4#random variable
N_female<-6#random variable 

plot(x=2,y=3)
legend("topright",legend=c(bquote('N'['M']*' = '*.( N_male)),
bquote('N'['M']*' = '*.( N_female))),
text.col="black",box.col=0, bty="n", cex = .75, lty= c(1,2))  #this legend    does not evaluate the bquote part
```

Comment: Do not edit question titles to include comments on the status of the question. If an answer solved your problem, click the check mark next to it and the question will automatically be labelled as "solved".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `as.expression` with your `bquote` inside the `c` call.

```
my.expressions <-c(as.expression(bquote('N'['F']*' = '*.( N_female))),as.expression(bquote('N'['M']*' = '*.( N_male))) )

N_male<-4#random variable
N_female<-6#random variable
plot(x=2,y=3)#random plot
legend("topright",legend=my.expressions,
text.col="black",box.col=0, bty="n", cex = .75, lty= c(2:3))
```

[image]

Comment: @P Lapointe How did you know what to do? I spent quite a few late ours on this and  my closes solution was to  call 'legend' multiple times, One for each line.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
plot(x=2,y=3)
legend("topright",legend=c(expression(paste('N'[M], ' = ', 4)),
                           expression(paste('N'[F], ' = ', 6))),
       text.col="black",box.col=0, bty="n", cex = .75, lty= c(1,2))
```

I tested other approaches. It seems that using variable and subscript in `lengend` together is impossible. Waiting for answers from master-hand!!

Comment: @ Ven Yao  How would you get your code to evaluate N_male and N_female variables? My code has functions to produce N_male and N_female variables so it needs to be able to update/change.

Comment: I did test my code. I added a few comments to make it clearer. The 'N_male<-4' and the 'N_female<-6' usually have functions to produce the values but I just made random numbers for this example. My goal is to have the legend able to interpret the subcripts and variables.

Comment: How would i subscript a variable ? i have a subscript that changes and is contained in a variable . For example my title should be Q500 where 500 can change to another number like 100, 20 etc. how can i ensure that 500 and the others are subscripted? Essentially the unsubscribed  expression would be bquote(“Q”~.(T)). I want the .(T) which takes on the values 30,100, 500, 1000 etc to be returned as a subscript